# Heroku asset pre compile locally did not show on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

after make a couple of tests with the assets locally and pre compile locally with production env, i decided to deploy to heroku. but first i removed the assets from the public folder commit and deploy.

after deployed the images, css's and javascript did not show on heroku.

i've tried to pre compile it on the terminal and did not show either.

i've searched into heroku docs and did not find anything related to it.

someone that know about heroku can help please?

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production on ⬢ app... up, run.6445 (Free)
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

I, [2018-04-28T00:34:53.297091 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-6530ec3783a5066dace59576978030c61110e689042a33aaabfa02bab8729a22.js
I, [2018-04-28T00:34:53.298286 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-6530ec3783a5066dace59576978030c61110e689042a33aaabfa02bab8729a22.js.gz
I, [2018-04-28T00:34:53.404455 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-888a5e4ac602e29fa84543f0d08fdf1f1f8821de0be9809aabb90dd2b5ac27ad.css
I, [2018-04-28T00:34:53.405133 #4]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-888a5e4ac602e29fa84543f0d08fdf1f1f8821de0be9809aabb90dd2b5ac27ad.css.gz







2018-04-28T01:02:42.479552+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.479553+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.479555+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.479556+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:632:in `handle_request'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.479576+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.479578+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `block in run'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.479579+00:00 app[web.1]: [d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2018-04-28T01:02:42.427445+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/sqre-14c09561486ba385a8a62bc0a8b41e03638a6334648113a7f28be47271eccb5e.png" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=bce0c62c-3568-44e4-adeb-74ed17691890 fwd="186.237.160.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-04-28T01:02:42.480067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/iore-583714033cab0d76045a8d4bbfb2326983f40d5c2cfa239e9527da9617686e6b.png" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=d7e41abe-2ebd-45bd-837f-04c140203f42 fwd="186.237.160.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2018-04-28T01:02:42.466234+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-888a5e4ac602e29fa84543f0d08fdf1f1f8821de0be9809aabb90dd2b5ac27ad.css" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=e083a6e2-dfd7-4d75-ae15-dac0eeaa7e1e fwd="186.237.160.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
```

Comment: Can you share the request log?

Comment: How are you including your assets in the view?

Comment: well i did not changed the rails default  still the

   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
                    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you precompile it yourself via Heroku client tool, you should restart your dynos to see the change. Try `heroku restart` and see if it works

Comment: The Lazy Log, thank you but the css still not showing, if i access the css on page source shows:

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

but the js shows

Comment: In fact, this will have the opposite effect on Heroku. Its [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Anything you write to the filesystem will be lost when the dyno restarts (even if you don't restart it manually this is a problem—dynos are [automatically restarted at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)). The assets need to be compiled during the build process or stored on a third-party service [like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Comment: @lula I just feel there is something wrong in your configuration. Can you confirm if you can see the CSS files in your local when you run the assets precompile command? You can also check in Heroku by run `heroku console` and then run `Dir['public/assets/*']`

Answer (score 1):

The assets will need to be complied either before, or when the app is deployed. In my experience this is typically done with a Heroku buildpack.

Look here. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-4-x-applications

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks